# como puedo realizar el siguiente código en c++ con while

Tags: dev-c++

Recibir una cantidad de numeros desconocida y detenerse cuando el numero recibido sea 0 o menor a uno, e indique cual es el mayor, cual es el menor y cual es el promedio

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado? Si solo dices tengo este deber resuelvan no es bien recibido.

Comment: Para recibir una cantidad de números desconocida y detenerse cuando el numero recibido sea 0 o menor a uno, indicando cuál es el mayor, menor y el promedio, tienes  que solicitar una cantidad arbitraria de números (hasta recibir valores menores a uno) y sacar el menor, mayor y la media.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva, pero asumí que los números que serán introducidos son enteros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numero;
    int suma=0;
    int contador=0;
    int mayor=-1;
    int menor=INT_MAX;
    while(true){
        cin>>numero;
        if(numero<1){
            break;
        }
        suma+=numero;
        contador++;
        if(mayor<numero){
            mayor=numero;
        }
        if(menor>numero){
            menor=numero;
        }
    }
    float promedio=0;
    if(contador>0){
        promedio=float(suma)/float(contador);
    }
    cout << "Mayor número: " << mayor << "\n" << "Menor número: " << menor << "\n" << "Promedio: " << promedio << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas mal formuladas y que no agreguen el código que han intentado y así evitar presunciones como bien lo has dicho **"pero asumí"**

Comment: gracias me funciono bien el código yo no lo lograba hacer porque no declaraba la variable ya que no sabia como agregar la siguiente variable  int menor=INT_MAX;

Comment: fijate que lo sise en  for con una variable inicia=1 y una variable final max=20